# Visualization of plots in windows 10 terminal

Tags: python, windows, plot

I have two systems one is ubuntu and another one is windows.
I usually connect my workplace server using "ssh -x abcs@xyz.edu" from both ubuntu and windows.
In Ubuntu, I can see plots (let's say I use matplotlib, python to plot something) in the terminals but not in windows 10.

I like to know if there is any visualization software or tools are there which help to see the plots within the windows terminals.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using SSH software for Windows that has support for X windowing system such as putty. Here are some resources to get you started with putty:

- https://www.putty.org/
- https://superuser.com/questions/119792/how-to-use-x11-forwarding-with-putty

Alternatively, You could use windows subsystem for linux, WSL, and use it have Ubuntu desktop environment on windows machine. From the Ubuntu WSL you can again use ssh -x abcs@xyz.edu like you would on native linux machine.

To get started with WSL, take a look here

- https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-wsl2-windows-10